# How do I fix a project with a outdated camera?

Tags: java, linux, camera, crash, project

Picture 3 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIWRA.png) Start Preview leads me here. Not sure what to do.

Picture 2 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N00ld.png) Blue line gets me here, line 617

Picture 1 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsDq5.png) Points to the problem. So I hit the blue line.

(I tried replacing camera with camera2 or cameraX. Not working. )

How do I run this project in android studios in linux? https://github.com/DhananjaiH/MeasureCam

I run the app and it tells me that the line that says camera.startPreview(); is problematic. I open start preview, and it points to a different file that has a line - "public native final void startPreview();" . Not sure what it wants from me. The app just keeps shutting down. I then deleted the first line of camera.startPreview(); and it runs the app, but without the camera.

Comment: What do you mean by "it says the line ... is problematic"? Do you get an error message? If so, then what is the exact error message? It contains important information that tells you what exactly the problem is, so you need to include it in your question here.

Comment: Okay. I made it clearer, I think. @Jesper

Answer (score 0):

The old camera API is deprecated, but it's only a warning - you should be able to use it just fine if you ignore the deprecation warnings (or suppress them).

`Camera.startPreview()` is an Android SDK API, so you can't look into its code (the SDK just comes with stubs, not implementations, which is why you see an empty method).

If what you're seeing isn't a deprecation warning, you'll need to explain what you are seeing in more detail. It's unclear what exactly happens when the app shuts down - where are you running it, and what logs are you seeing?